# reorder byte order in hex string (python)

Tags: python, string, hex, swap, python-2.x

I want to build a small formatter in python giving me back the numeric
values embedded in lines of hex strings.

It is a central part of my formatter and should be reasonable fast to
format more than 100 lines/sec (each line about ~100 chars).

The code below should give an example where I'm currently blocked.

'data_string_in_orig' shows the given input format. It has to be
byte swapped for each word. The swap from 'data_string_in_orig' to
'data_string_in_swapped' is needed. In the end I need the structure
access as shown. The expected result is within the comment.

Thanks in advance
Wolfgang R

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import binascii
import struct

## 'uint32 double'
data_string_in_orig    = 'b62e000052e366667a66408d'
data_string_in_swapped = '2eb60000e3526666667a8d40'
print data_string_in_orig

packed_data = binascii.unhexlify(data_string_in_swapped)
s = struct.Struct('<Id')
unpacked_data = s.unpack_from(packed_data, 0)  
print 'Unpacked Values:', unpacked_data

## Unpacked Values: (46638, 943.29999999943209)

exit(0)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`array.arrays` have a [byteswap method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap):

```
import binascii
import struct
import array
x = binascii.unhexlify('b62e000052e366667a66408d')
y = array.array('h', x)  
y.byteswap()
s = struct.Struct('<Id')
print(s.unpack_from(y))

# (46638, 943.2999999994321)
```

The `h` in `array.array('h', x)` was chosen because it tells `array.array` to regard the data in `x` as an array of 2-byte shorts. The important thing is that each item be regarded as being 2-bytes long. `H`, which signifies 2-byte unsigned short, works just as well.

Comment: `array.byteswap`. Sweet. Guess I'll go ahead and not post the kludgy unpack big-endian / repack little-endian solution I had cooking...

Comment: Go ahead and post it! Having more than one way to solve a problem can be useful.

Comment: Thanks, this was fast and perfect for me. By the way 100k lines in 5 sec.

Answer (score 11):

This should do exactly what unutbu's version does, but might be slightly easier to follow for some...

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from struct import pack, unpack
orig = unhexlify('b62e000052e366667a66408d')
swapped = pack('<6h', *unpack('>6h', orig))
print unpack('<Id', swapped)

# (46638, 943.2999999994321)
```

Basically, unpack 6 shorts big-endian, repack as 6 shorts little-endian.

Again, same thing that unutbu's code does, and you should use his.

**edit** Just realized I get to use my favorite Python idiom for this... Don't do this either:

```
orig = 'b62e000052e366667a66408d'
swap =''.join(sum([(c,d,a,b) for a,b,c,d in zip(*[iter(orig)]*4)], ()))
# '2eb60000e3526666667a8d40'
```

Answer (score 2):

The swap from 'data_string_in_orig' to 'data_string_in_swapped' may also be done with comprehensions without using any imports:

```
>>> d = 'b62e000052e366667a66408d'
>>> "".join([m[2:4]+m[0:2] for m in [d[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(d),4)]])
'2eb60000e3526666667a8d40'
```

The comprehension works for swapping byte order in hex strings representing 16-bit words. Modifying it for a different word-length is trivial. We can make a general hex digit order swap function also:

```
def swap_order(d, wsz=4, gsz=2 ):
    return "".join(["".join([m[i:i+gsz] for i in range(wsz-gsz,-gsz,-gsz)]) for m in [d[i:i+wsz] for i in range(0,len(d),wsz)]])
```

The input params are:

d : the input hex string

wsz: the word-size in nibbles (e.g for 16-bit words wsz=4, for 32-bit words wsz=8)

gsz: the number of nibbles which stay together (e.g for reordering bytes gsz=2, for reordering 16-bit words gsz = 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
import binascii, tkinter, array
from tkinter import *

infile_read = filedialog.askopenfilename()

with open(infile, 'rb') as infile_:
    infile_read = infile_.read()

x = (infile_read)
y = array.array('l', x)
y.byteswap()
swapped = (binascii.hexlify(y))
```

This is a 32 bit unsigned short swap i achieved with code very much the same as "unutbu's"  answer just a little bit easier to understand. And technically binascii is not needed for the swap. Only array.byteswap is needed.