# Binary to hex in Python, low-nibble first encoding

Tags: python, encoding, hex, binary-data, packing

I have a protocol that requires converting binary data to and from a hex-encoded string where the low-nibble (lower 4 bits of each byte) come first - so for example the Python string '\xab\xcd' would be encoded as 'badc'. This odd format comes from the PHP/Perl `pack` and `unpack` functions with the `h*` format (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).

Obviously plain `binascii.hexlify()` et al won't achieve this. I've tried using various formats with the `struct` module as well as `array` byteswapping [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155570/reorder-byte-order-in-hex-string-python) but couldn't get it to work.

I ended up solving it with some old-fashioned bit juggling like this:

```
def to_low_nibble_hex(value):
    """Convert a binary string to hex using low-nibble first encoding
    """
    r = []
    for c in value:
        c = ord(c)
        hb = (0x0f & c) << 4
        lb = (0xf0 & c) >> 4
        nc = chr(hb | lb)
        r += [nc]
    return binascii.hexlify(''.join(r))
```

This seems to work well in my case but I was wondering if anyone can suggest a more formal approach.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to precalculate a translation table and then simply apply it using [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

```
_translation = bytearray(((0x0f & c) << 4 | (0xf0 & c) >> 4)
                         for c in range(256))

def to_low_nibble_hex(value):
    return binascii.hexlify(value.translate(_translation))
```

This also works on python3 without modification, although there you could replace `bytearray` with `bytes`

Comment: This indeed looks clean and efficient, and I will probably adopt it, so thanks! However I'm still wondering if there is a more standard solution.