# How to store the data in little endian format in a binary file in Python

Tags: python, file, binaryfiles, endianness, binascii

I have a binary file. I want to read hexadecimal data from the terminal in my python code. I am executing the program as follows:
python hello.py "2DB6C" "CDEF"

"2DB6C" :- (Address in hex) Indicates GoTo address <2DB6C> in the temp.bin file, where I  want to start writing the data.

"CDEF" :- Data to be written in binary file. Remember the data is given in the hex format.

I want to write the data in the small endian format. But it is not working for me.

```
file = open("temp.bin", "r+b")
file.seek(4)
datatomodify = "CDEF"
data = binascii.unhexlify(datatomodify)
print ("data :", data, "offset addr :", hex(file.tell()))
file.write(data)
print ("after writing addr :", hex(file.tell()))
file.close()
```

It is writing in the file as "CDEF". But I want to write the data in the little endian format.

Kindly help me in fixing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155570/reorder-byte-order-in-hex-string-python

Comment: `data` has type `bytes`.  A stream of bytes doesn't have an endianess, because all the values in the object are 8 bit.  Endianess applies to, for example, 16 bit and 32 bit integers.  For those, the endianess specifies the order of the bytes used to represent the integers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) package. Assuming your two numbers are unsigned longs of 4 Bytes:

```
from struct import *
# data will contain a binary message packed with two Long (4 bytes)
data = pack('<LL', 1, 2)      # < little endian
                              # L first long of value 1
                              # L second long of value 2
# 0100000002000000
```

And of course you need to convert your hex strings into long numbers. You could reverse the hex strings, but I think it is errorprone.